# using multiple authorization elements in web.config

Tags: asp.net, web-config, authorization

Is it possible to use multiple authorization elements in a single web.config to allow additional users access to one file?

E.g., I would like to allow User1 access to the whole application (including Page1.aspx), and User2 access to only Page1.aspx:

```
<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <allow users="DOMAIN\User1" />
    <deny users="*" />
  </authorization>
</system.web>
<location path="~/Page1.aspx">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="DOMAIN\User2" />
      <deny users="*" />
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can use a comma delimited list of users, so there should be no need for using multiple authorization elements for a single resource.

Also, it is generally better to rely on roles instead of specific users.  Since it appears you are using AD, then you can use a security group or something similar for the roles.

Comment: I can't create new groups to encapsulate the roles so I have to use users.  The point I am making is that User1 should have inherited rights to Page1.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the `<deny users="*" />` from the Page1.aspx authorization section, you should get what you want. It will allow User2 to use just that page, and User1's authorization to everything will still apply to this page as well.

Here's [a pretty good tutorial](http://www.asp.net/security/tutorials/user-based-authorization-cs) on all things related to authorization.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work.  If I use my own account as User2, I don't get access to Page1.aspx

Comment: Looks like the problem was only that the asp.net did not expect the ~/ on the 2nd rule. Removing that worked.